# Tricky Java program

Tags: java

Look at the code below and please help me solve the trick.

```
class TestTrick{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }

    static marker()
    {

    System.out.println("programe executed");

    }

}
```

The result required from this program is that the program should print
`program executed`, meaning that the `marker` method should be executed. But there are some rules:

1. Nothing should be written in both the methods.
2. No other class can be added to the program.
3. The program must execute the output statement in the marker method.

It's been three days and I am unable to solve the problem because I am not a Java programmer. I have searched everything on internet to get a clue but I failed. Please
someone help me run this program by strictly following the rules.

Comment: If this is an homework, mark it as one.

Comment: maybe switch the names of the functions :p? or better, just comment the end of the first and the beginning of the second method !

Comment: If you aren't a Java programmer, why are you taking Java homework?

Comment: As a good practice, use camel case names for classes. Like `TestTrick` and name the containing file too accordingly. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. i will surely keep that in mind.

Comment: In the question, if `static marker()` is a method then it should have some return type. That's the reason I got confused. Or else static initialization block is a simple answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what they're looking for is a [*static initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

```
static {
    marker();
}
```

This gets run when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you don't want a method for your marker - you just want a static initialization block:

```
class Trick {
    // not a method, just something to execute when the class is loaded
    static { System.out.println("executed"); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Results: http://ideone.com/bQAgT

If you've been provided the code already (which I'm not sure you have because `static marker()` isn't valid code) then you can simply call `marker()` from your `static` block.

Comment: This answer doesn't satisfy *3. the program must execute the output statment in the marker method*. however it does produce the same output

Comment: @Brad the entire set constraints wasn't very clear. Given that the code provided in the OP didn't compile, I had to make some assumptions about what was and wasn't factually correct. I believe I have covered the two most probable cases in my answer.

Comment: That's a fair comment glowcoder, and I didn't mark down your answer. I was just commenting on it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use static initializer, that will be executed before the Main method can be run.

```
static {
     marker();
}
```

Comment: Not a "static constructor", but a static block.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` block will do the trick for you. But you have a syntax error in your program. Since `marker` is a method, it must have a return type. I am assuming `void`.

```
class testTrick {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }

    static void marker() {
        System.out.println("programe executed");
    }

    static {
        marker();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy.  In the class add a static constructor to call the marker method and then in the constructor put in a system.exit

Comment: "Nothing should be written in both the methods." Besides, why would you need a `System.exit()`? The program will end on its own.

Answer (score 1):

An even trickier program is

```
class testTrick {
    static { marker(); System.exit(0); } static void marker() {
        System.out.println("program executed");
    }
}
```

Note: marker has to provide a return type e.g. `void` or it won't compile.  You can keep the main() method if you like, but it is never called.

The static initialiser is called before the main method so it can call another method and it can exit before you see a message saying no main() method found.

Answer (score 0):

```
class testTrick
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }

    static 
    {
        marker();
    }

    static void marker()
    {
        System.out.println("programe executed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does this follow your rules ?, creating a static block will always execute as it gets stored along with the class files and it doen need a main method to call

```
class TestTrick{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }

    static marker()
    {

    System.out.println("programe executed");

    }

}
```

Comment: oops  , seems like answered a question wchich already has the same ans , well may be a little explanation helps , though its a old question

Answer (score 0):

```
public class M
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
    static
    {
        marker();
    }
    public static void marker()
    {
         System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestTrick{
public static void main(String args[])
{

}

static{
    marker();}
static void marker(){

System.out.println("programe executed");

}
```

Look at the requirements. You can do anything you want as long as you do not alter the methods.

So a static block(which will always execute in a program) is needed. Its not a method, and you can call `marker()` from there(which btw needs to be assigned a return type)

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;

System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score -2):

You would need to call the marker method in the main method ie; something like this:

```
class testTrick {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        marker();
    }

    static void marker() {
        System.out.println("programe executed");
    }

}
```

Comment: "Nothing should be written in both the methods."